# Check if Null before Splitting - Javascript

Tags: javascript, split, null

I have this code snippet in a slider script:

```
var shareURLParts = val.split(/\?|\&/g),
                    shareURLString = '';
```

How would I check if `val` equals `null` BEFORE splitting it?

Comment: `var shareURLParts = val && val.split(/\?|\&/g), shareURLString = '';`

Comment: `var shareURLParts = val ? val.split(/\?|\&/g) : null,
                    shareURLString = '';`

Comment: `val === null`? It's unclear what you're asking. What do you want to do if `val` is `null`?